# Client to send SOAP request and receive response

Tags: c#, soap, webservice-client

Trying to create a C# client (will be developed as a Windows service) that sends SOAP requests to a web service (and gets the results).

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862965/sending-and-receiving-soap-xml) I saw this code:

```
protected virtual WebRequest CreateRequest(ISoapMessage soapMessage)
{
    var wr = WebRequest.Create(soapMessage.Uri);
    wr.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
    wr.ContentLength = soapMessage.ContentXml.Length;

    wr.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", soapMessage.SoapAction);
    wr.Credentials = soapMessage.Credentials;
    wr.Method = "POST";
    wr.GetRequestStream().Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soapMessage.ContentXml), 0, soapMessage.ContentXml.Length);

    return wr;
}

public interface ISoapMessage
{
    string Uri { get; }
    string ContentXml { get; }
    string SoapAction { get; }
    ICredentials Credentials { get; }
}
```

Looks nice, anyone knows how to use it and if it is the best practice?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

I normally use another way to do the same

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public static void CallWebService()
{
    var _url = "http://xxxxxxxxx/Service1.asmx";
    var _action = "http://xxxxxxxx/Service1.asmx?op=HelloWorld";

    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
    InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

    // begin async call to web request.
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

    // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
    // do something usefull here like update your UI.
    asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    // get the response from the completed web request.
    string soapResult;
    using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Console.Write(soapResult);        
    }
}

private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    return webRequest;
}

private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope()
{
    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeDocument = new XmlDocument();
    soapEnvelopeDocument.LoadXml(
    @"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
               xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"" 
               xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <HelloWorld xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"" 
                SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"">
                <int1 xsi:type=""xsd:integer"">12</int1>
                <int2 xsi:type=""xsd:integer"">32</int2>
            </HelloWorld>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>");
    return soapEnvelopeDocument;
}

private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
    using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is samething, But i have put everything here, including the SOAP request string.

Comment: nice, 2 more question, my test server uses https with self generated certification, I have a method to accespt the certification, where to impliment? and how to add the use of username and passowrd? my server require username and password!

Comment: ok, I think you have to put that in SOAP request, if you have a sample of request payload, then you can build a request just like that. Not sure what kind of security you use, If you are using WS-Security then the username and password you can pass with your SOAP request Header.

Comment: I'm thinking in something like this HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
            webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

Comment: the web-service I'm dealing with is the Exchange Web Service!

Comment: NetworkCredential is required if your asmx file has the Windows authentication. I think i can give you one url which has handful of information about webservice authentication and autherization http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020312.htm

Comment: I don't like it, it doesn't have any Error handling for connection not found etc.

Comment: @hamish: this is just a conceptual code snippet. Don't consider it as a production quality code.

Comment: Extremely helpful and helped me work through using Telerik Fiddler to manual POST to my web service, because I could see all the headers you set. Thanks very much.

Comment: I had to add: webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; to get the authentication to work

Comment: i have error Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting) any one have idea

Comment: This worked perfectly. The only difference this was from vb.net was that the ContentType needs to be as follows: webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"""

Comment: how received file and transform in PDF?

Comment: I'm having trouble capturing the soap fault with this approach

Comment: To resolve a Internal Server 500 Error, I had to use the following adjustments to the URL and header:

var _url = "http://xxxxxxxxx/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld";

webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAP:Action");

Comment: @KBBWrite, would you provide an example code of how to Create a soap envelope from class object?

Answer (score 74):

I got this simple solution [here](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=1893):

**Sending SOAP request and receiving response in .NET 4.0 C# without using the WSDL or proxy classes:**

```
class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Execute a Soap WebService call
        /// </summary>
        public static void Execute()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest();
            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
            soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                  <soap:Body>
                    <HelloWorld xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"" />
                  </soap:Body>
                </soap:Envelope>");

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a soap webrequest to [Url]
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest()
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:56405/WebService1.asmx?op=HelloWorld");
            webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:Action");
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Execute();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can we create soap xml client with out using  string soap xml. With using c#  code.  Like as  :
var request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = Common.Method;
For example one c# method that creates more than one soap xml client to the different wsdl services with parameters.

Comment: I am getting the following error and the code terminates: **'soap' is an undeclared prefix. Line 2, position 18.** am I missing something? The SOAP UI request for my webservice can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430398/c-sharp-runtime-error-when-implementing-wsse-security-headers-with-custom-fields

Comment: Works with `webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/.....");` Check the SOAP Action that's in SoapUI and use that.

Comment: I get an error when I use the colon in the SOAPAction header. I have to do: webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction", "SomeAction");

Comment: how received file and transform in PDF?

Answer (score 37):

I think there is a simpler way:

```
 public async Task<string> CreateSoapEnvelope()
 {
      string soapString = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
          <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
              <soap:Body>
                  <HelloWorld xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"" />
              </soap:Body>
          </soap:Envelope>";

          HttpResponseMessage response = await PostXmlRequest("your_url_here", soapString);
          string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

      return content;
 }

 public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostXmlRequest(string baseUrl, string xmlString)
 {
      using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
      {
          var httpContent = new StringContent(xmlString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
          httpContent.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld");

          return await httpClient.PostAsync(baseUrl, httpContent);
       }
 }
```

Comment: This worked like a champ.  I added parameters to the CreateSoapEnvelope method to be able to pass in the string XML, post URL, and action URL to make the methods reusable and it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: best answer for my opinion because it uses more relevant HttpClient instead of obsolete WebResponse.

Comment: Hi , I have soap:header which containse token , i sent the request but somehow the server is not picking up the token.

Answer (score 19):

The best practice is to reference the WSDL and use it like a web service reference.
It's easier and works better, but if you don't have the WSDL, the XSD definitions are a good piece of code.

Comment: How can I add custom header for SOAP request If I add WSDL as a web service reference and also end points???

Comment: You mention to do this, any reference on HOW to do this?

Comment: If the WSDL doesnt want a custom header, then you shouldnt be adding one.

Comment: Basically what is needed to send - receive SOAP? Is it enough to use binding which supports SOAP like wsHttpBinding and reference WSDL? Everything else is same as using REST (calling WCF methods, receiving response)?

Comment: I agreed with the WSDL's, the former is way more complex and unnecessary. All you need is to go onto Service References in your project (In older versions of Visual Studio), right click, add service reference and input the correct details. A c# object is created that must be created as a variable. All functionality of the WSDL service is then exposed through code

Comment: Anyone can show me an example of this please. i tried using this method i keep getting pointer null error

Answer (score 17):

I wrote a more general helper class which accepts a string-based dictionary of custom parameters, so that they can be set by the caller without having to hard-code them. It goes without saying that you should only use such method when you want (or need) to manually issue a SOAP-based web service: in most common scenarios the recommended approach would be using the Web Service WSDL together with the **Add Service Reference** Visual Studio feature instead.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace Ryadel.Web.SOAP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class to send custom SOAP requests.
    /// </summary>
    public static class SOAPHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a custom sync SOAP request to given URL and receive a request
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">The WebService endpoint URL</param>
        /// <param name="action">The WebService action name</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">A dictionary containing the parameters in a key-value fashion</param>
        /// <param name="soapAction">The SOAPAction value, as specified in the Web Service's WSDL (or NULL to use the url parameter)</param>
        /// <param name="useSOAP12">Set this to TRUE to use the SOAP v1.2 protocol, FALSE to use the SOAP v1.1 (default)</param>
        /// <returns>A string containing the raw Web Service response</returns>
        public static string SendSOAPRequest(string url, string action, Dictionary<string, string> parameters, string soapAction = null, bool useSOAP12 = false)
        {
            // Create the SOAP envelope
            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
            var xmlStr = (useSOAP12)
                ? @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
                      xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""
                      xmlns:soap12=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"">
                      <soap12:Body>
                        <{0} xmlns=""{1}"">{2}</{0}>
                      </soap12:Body>
                    </soap12:Envelope>"
                : @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
                        xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
                        xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
                        <soap:Body>
                           <{0} xmlns=""{1}"">{2}</{0}>
                        </soap:Body>
                    </soap:Envelope>";
            string parms = string.Join(string.Empty, parameters.Select(kv => String.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", kv.Key, kv.Value)).ToArray());
            var s = String.Format(xmlStr, action, new Uri(url).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/", parms);
            soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(s);

            // Create the web request
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", soapAction ?? url);
            webRequest.ContentType = (useSOAP12) ? "application/soap+xml;charset=\"utf-8\"" : "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = (useSOAP12) ? "application/soap+xml" : "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";

            // Insert SOAP envelope
            using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }

            // Send request and retrieve result
            string result;
            using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = rd.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

For additional info & details regarding this class you can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/soap-web-service-request-asp-net-c-sharp-wsdl-proxy-soapclient/) on my blog.

Answer (score 1):

So this is my final code after googling for 2 days on how to add a namespace and make soap request along with the SOAP envelope without adding proxy/Service Reference

```
class Request
{
    public static void Execute(string XML)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest();
            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
            soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(AppendEnvelope(AddNamespace(XML)));

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest()
    {
        string ICMURL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ICMUrl");
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;

        try
        {
            webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ICMURL);
            webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:Action");
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return webRequest;
    }

    private static string AddNamespace(string XML)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {

            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.LoadXml(XML);

            XmlElement temproot = xdoc.CreateElement("ws", "Request", "http://example.com/");
            temproot.InnerXml = xdoc.DocumentElement.InnerXml;
            result = temproot.OuterXml;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static string AppendEnvelope(string data)
    {
        string head= @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" ><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body>";
        string end = @"</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
        return head + data + end;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, and pretty close to debiasej approach. Since a SOAP request is just a HTTP request, you can simply perform a GET or POST using with HTTP client, but it's not mandatory to build SOAP envelope.

Something like this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HGF.Infraestructure.Communications
{
    public class SOAPSample
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
        private readonly ILogger<DocumentProvider> _logger;

        public SOAPSample(ILogger<DocumentProvider> logger,
                          IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<string> UsingGet(int value1, int value2)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
                var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://hostname.com/webservice.asmx/SampleMethod?value1={value1}&value2={value2}", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

                //NULL check, HTTP Status Check....

                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Oops! Something went wrong");
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }


        public async Task<string> UsingPost(int value1, int value2)
        {
            try
            {
                var content = new StringContent($"value1={value1}&value2={value2}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
                var response = await client.PostAsync("https://hostname.com/webservice.asmx/SampleMethod", content);

                //NULL check, HTTP Status Check....

                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Oops! Something went wrong");
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, it depends on your scenario. If the payload is too complex, then this won't work

Answer (score -5):

Call SOAP webservice in c#

```
using (var client = new UpdatedOutlookServiceReferenceAPI.OutlookServiceSoapClient("OutlookServiceSoap"))
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var result = client.UploadAttachmentBase64(GUID, FinalFileName, fileURL);

    if (result == true)
    {
        resultFlag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        resultFlag = false;
    }
    LogWriter.LogWrite1("resultFlag : " + resultFlag);
}
```

Comment: What is `new UpdatedOutlookServiceReferenceAPI.OutlookServiceSoapClient()` ?

Comment: It is look like he added a service reference using WDSL. Then, he is using the generated service reference to call SAOP method. Something like this https://wiki.cloud.clicksoftware.com/fsedoc/en/development/developing-with-the-service-edge-apis/developing-with-the-web-service-api/calling-a-web-service-via-a-service-reference