# How to install svcutil.exe under Windows 10

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, code-generation

I am desperately searching for a way to install `svcutil.exe` because I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973819/converting-wsdl-to-c-sharp-classes) and elsewhere that this was the way to compile a WSDL into C# code. I tried it via Windows SDK install, which yielded a folder of about 1K installers of whom I don't know which one to start. Any guidance is appreciated.

NB: I am currently using Visual Studio 2017 Preview, is that related somehow?

Comment: You don't have that exe at all? Its usually available via the  "Developer command prompt for vs2017" start menu item.

Comment: @AlexK. will try that out and tell you if it helped, thanks

Comment: @AlexK. thanks that helped! Coming from Unix/Linux I was expecting these tools to be in the path of the cmd, but it isn't

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @AlexK. pointed out in his comment, the `svcutil.exe` is available via the "Developer command prompt for vs2017" start menu item.

I found out the path via `where svcutil` and added it to my PATH environment variable. Now I can use it as required. Thanks again!

Answer (score 24):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools

Comment: As of today (2019-02-17):   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\x64

Comment: Thanks, in my case it was in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\