# Generate C# class from WSDL file

Tags: c#, .net, wsdl

I'm trying generate several C# classes from WSDL file.
I tried to use an google to get information how I can convert it([Converting WSDL to C# classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973819/converting-wsdl-to-c-sharp-classes)), but unfortunately it doesn't help. If you can help me - thanks.
My file at some website: https://Example/Example.wsdl - it's not correct way, just example.
How I can convert it to C# class by VisualStudio 2019.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R4B6.png)

Comment: Have you tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Comment: It's converted to asmx file and it doesn't create several files - its create only one. Attached screen with connected service

Answer (score 4):

In your case there is a way to convert the file to c# file. Do as following.

- Open Visual Studio Command prompt as a administrator by going to
  `Start menu > All Programs > Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 > Visual    Studio Tools > Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019`.
- Put your WSDL file in somewhere accessible e.g. in this case I will put it in my C drive and getting output CS class in C drive too but    you can change it. Type this command and press okay

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 19.0\VC>wsdl /l:C# /out:C:\OutPutClassName.cs
  C:\myWebService.wsdl

This process will create your WSDL file to the C# class file on the same folder.