# Step to call a soap webservice in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono

I have been struggling to call a asmx web service using xamarin form. I added my web service in the PLC project by `right click` => `Add` => `service reference`. Below is the way I call it. I am using android phone for this.

```
var forms = new ServiceReference.RSDSoapClient();
forms.SyncFormScoreCompleted += (object sender, SyncFormScoreCompletedEventArgs 
e) => {
var result= e.Result.ToString();}; //The results alwasy null.

}
test.SyncFormScoreAsync();
```

Error:

> at EngenIBDApplication.ServiceReference.RSDSoapClient.EndSyncFormScore
>   (IAsyncResult result) [0x00009] in
>   c:\Projects\EngenIBDApplication\EngenIBDApplication\EngenIBDApplication\Service
>   References\ServiceReference\Reference.cs:3387  at
>   EngenIBDApplication.ServiceReference.RSDSoapClient.OnEndSyncFormScore
>   (IAsyncResult result) [0x00001] in
>   c:\Projects\EngenIBDApplication\EngenIBDApplication\EngenIBDApplication\Service
>   References\ServiceReference\Reference.cs:3395  at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1+c__AnonStorey0[TChannel].<>m__0
>   (IAsyncResult ar) [0x00006] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:242

Is there anything I must do?

Comment: In an era of micro services, it is recommended to convert the SOAP services to REST and then use`HttpClient` to consume them.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have managed to do this like this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20108971/3049612

Comment: Post your answer and accept it.