# Undeclared prefix while loading SOAP xml

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I've received documentation from a client to use the below SOAP request. I've never worked with SOAP before and I'm using the solution listed in this question: [Client to send SOAP request and received response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/c-sharp-client-send-soap-request-and-get-results)

However, when `soapEnvelop.LoadXml` is run I get: `'head' is an undeclared prefix. Line 5, position 39.`

Here is the SOAP xml I received from my client:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
               xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
               xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <soap:Header>
        <head:CustomCredentials>
            <head:UserName>Username</head:UserName>
            <head:Password>Password</head:Password>
            <head:Source>Code</head:Source>
            <head:CurrentCulture>en-CA</head:CurrentCulture>
        </head:CustomCredentials>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <WebServiceMethodName xmlns='Web Service Namespace' />                                        
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm not entierly sure what to do here. From googling I believe that the element head just doesn't exist in the namespace.

Comment: 'head:xxxxxx' elements use the 'head' prefix but you don't have a xmlns:head='??????' declared

Comment: Like I said I'm just copy pasting what I received. I'm not sure how I should add this.

Comment: Figure out what namespace URI should be there first. Someone defined it as a SOAP header. Once you have that URI, add "xmlns:head='{the URL you got}' to the top level element (like the xmlns:xsd=.., xmlns:soap=... ones)