# Ticket management in OTRS with C# via RPC.pl or generic interface

Tags: c#, otrs

I have check these sites:

http://blog.otrs.org/2012/10/03/easy-ticket-creation-via-generic-interface/

[Client to send SOAP request and received response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/c-sharp-client-send-soap-request-and-get-results)

I am not a Perl guy.  I have RPC enabled, I have the web service enabled.  However, when I try to do the C# code listed on some the pages I get a 500 from the server.

Am I missing a foundational part of this puzzle?  Is there more OTRS config that I need to do that I have not done?

Thanks!

P.S.

I have other links that I am unable to post due to my low rep.

Comment: Hi can you please specify what you are trying to do with the webservice? Do you know what the xml of the soap looks like? Maybe post a screen shot of the web service configuration in OTRS.

Comment: Create and view tickets.  The web service config is taken from this site:  http://doc.otrs.org/3.1/en/html/genericinterface-connectors.html  under the "Web Service Configuration" area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite hard to answer your question without seeing your C# code and your exact configuration. Here are some ideas for you to try and check

1. are you using  http://myOTRSurl.com/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/MyWebServiceName to access  the webservice?
2. Is there any debugging information in otrs. GO to 'Admin'->'Web Services' -> select the web service -> 'Debugger' -> view the request list for any information that can help you debug your specific problem
3. Debug your C# code to make sure the soap message is formed correctly with the tags opened and closed.
4. Go to the developer API for the ticketget http://dev.otrs.org/cvs/Kernel/GenericInterface/Operation/Ticket/TicketGet.html and http://dev.otrs.org/cvs/Kernel/GenericInterface/Operation/Ticket/TicketCreate.html are you providing the required parameters in the SOAP?

Hope this helps a bit. For more info you can read details in http://doc.otrs.org/3.2/en/html/genericinterface.html

Comment: The debugger was the missing key for me!  It allowed me to clean up the bad SOAP (I was missing a "CustomerUser" which was not in the documentation I had) and insert a ticket!  Thanks!