# Create soap web service client from wsdl with no contract methods

Tags: wcf, soap-client, wse

I'm stumped, probably because of not understanding something about soap services. When I create a service reference to the current public x12 health document submission service interface:

```
http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd
```

I get some classes that define what the body of the soap message can be, but I can't get a client proxy generated.

I would like to build my client with WCF, but in every example I find, they have an existing contract to generate a proxy. I don't have that luxury. The functions for the service are called via soap action.

I can manually generate the call with code similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-received-response) but the call is always rejected because the 'nonce is expired'.

The examples for WCF all have a nice contract in their WSDL so it seems simple, but it's useless code as I can't create any interface (automajically). For example, [Rick Strahl's blog post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/24/WCF-WSSecurity-and-WSE-Nonce-Authentication) answers many questions and seems great *if you have a contract message to call*. I would like to follow his approach but am stumped on creating the client (properly)!

So, I can build a legacy soap client with WSE 3, with guidance [here from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8728chd5(v=vs.100).aspx) but aren't we supposed to use WCF now? Even the post tags here say WSE is a last resort option.

Am I missing something about creating the client proxy?

So my question boils down to this: **How can I create the web service client proxy for a soap service with no contracts in WCF?**

Maybe I'm not understanding something about calling soap services, and could really use some help.

[EDIT: another thought - might I make my own manually built contract and thus generate a proxy with that? Not sure of the effect on XML output to the soap web service..ie, would the call look normal]

Comment: You need a WSDL, and don't ever use WSE. The XSD is not enough for calling a service.

Comment: The WSDL I supplied is the only one supplied. If I put ?wsdl after the vendor site I get "Error: Generic Error. Could not generate WSDL!" The Vendor imlements a Axis2 Web Service

Comment: I've created a sample project to demonstrate you a solution, please see my edited answer

Comment: You didn't post a WSDL URL, only an XSD

Comment: Wsdl url is http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.wsdl and in sample project https://bitbucket.org/polacekpavel/servicestacksample/src/51ab86e5a06cecaf7e59a812380a65767f2ebb29/Service%20References/CoreRule/CORE.wsdl?at=master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my sample project for this wsdl
https://bitbucket.org/polacekpavel/servicestacksample/src

Or you can use ChannelFactory for that http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms576132(v=vs.110).aspx
Assume you have this interface - change it to the real one.

```
[ServiceContract]               
public interface IMathService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Add(int a,int b);
}
```

then you can call it at runtime with custom configuration of ABC(address,binding,contract)

```
   //define binding 
    //assume your binding using basicHttp, change it if you are using something else
    BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();           

    //define endpoint url (where service is deployed)
    EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:11234/MathService.svc"); //change to real endpoint 

    //Use channel factory instead of generated one
    ChannelFactory<IMathservice> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMathservice>(myBinding, myEndpoint); //Change to you WCF interface
    IMathservice mathService= myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

    //and call it            
    var result = mathService.Add(1,1); //input to your method

    ((IClientChannel)mathService).Close();
    myChannelFactory.Close();
```

Comment: That assumes that he knows the contract. All he has is an XSD describing the message formats. That's not a contract.

Comment: I think message format is at http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.wsdl and there is a data type descriptions http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd so I think that is enough information for call

Comment: Then the OP should use "Add Service Reference" and refer to the WSDL.

Comment: Definitely. For me approach by channelFactory is more "clearer" than configuration hell and auto generated classes. But it's absolutely correct way to do this.

Comment: I did "Add Service Reference" but it offers no client proxy or service call as a result - that would have been mega easy and I wouldn't have to have asked this question. @polacekpavel How would you make the call? There is only the soap body class definitions from that WSDL - no message.

Comment: At dialog "Add service reference" write url http://caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.wsdl which is wsdl for this endpoint, this will generate proxy class and add configuration to you app.config/web.config then simple use generated proxy. CoreRule.CORETransactionsClient client = new CoreRule.CORETransactionsClient();
            client.BatchResultsAckSubmitTransaction(new CoreRule.COREEnvelopeBatchResultsAckSubmission()
            {
                ReceiverID = 122,
                //...
            });

Comment: And dont forget to change URL at app.config/web.config for real one <endpoint address="http://URL_OF_WEB_SERVICE" ... >

Comment: What the heck!?!? Every other time - EVERY OTHER TIME - I've done that, the References.cs file was empty...why would it suddenly work? NOW I have a client! Holy cow... Well, thanks though. In my disbelief, I just added it again from your link and it worked...

Comment: Yeah. I know that feeling. As the saying goes "Chuck Norris can configure WCF" :-)