# See SOAP/XML returned by WCF

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

Say I have the standard Service.svc deployed like this:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }
}
```

and a client like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client s1 = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
         string str = s1.GetData(1);

    }
}
```

The web service returns the following text to the str variable (as expected): "You entered: 1".  How do I see the SOAP/XML that was generated?

I realise I could use Fiddler, however I want to see it in .NET i.e. returned to the str variable..

Comment: you could hit the endpoint with function calls and parameters with an HTTP client instead of the service proxy I would imagine... what are you trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main benefits WCF has to offer is abstracting you from any serialization/transport issues. Since your service contract returns `CompositeType` you get an instance of it automatically reconstructed from the underlying XML message on the client side.

However, if you want to get a raw XML you can still do that by performing direct call depending on what transport is supported by your WCF server. if it's basicHttpBinding/wsHttpBinding you can perform HTTP request and read a response which will be pure XML. Of course, all the dirty work like authentication and security is on you.

If you need this just for debugging/studying purposes you can [enable message logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788183.aspx) or use standard [WcfTestClient.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.110).aspx) utility.

Comment: Thanks.  How do you: "perform HTTP request and read a response which will be pure XML"?

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-received-response