# C# replace \" for " in a string

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015, xml-parsing, .net-4.0

Hi I need to replace \" for " in a string. For example I have:

```
<![CDATA[<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>]]>
```

but I need:

```
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>]]>
```

This is for sending an inner XML within CDATA. My code below

```
    private static string GetAsCDATA(object oSrc /*inner Xml*/)
    {
        XmlSerializer oSerializer = new XmlSerializer(oSrc.GetType());
        StringBuilder oBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter oWriter = new EncodingStringWriter(oBuilder, Encoding.UTF8);
        oSerializer.Serialize(oWriter, oSrc);
        string sXml = oWriter.ToString();

        XmlDocument oDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlCDataSection oCData = oDoc.CreateCDataSection(sXml);
        sXml = oCData.OuterXml;

        return sXml;
    }
```

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: I suspect you haven't *actually* got those backslashes in the string. Are you looking in the debugger by any  chance? Try printing the string out on the console...

Comment: Thank you Jon, I copied from the debugger and tested by SoapUI and removing the backslash works! I don't figure out how remove this characters.

Comment: I'm not suggesting copying from the debugger. I'm suggesting that it's not really in the string at all. The debugger is just escaping the quote for you.

Comment: I fresh on this, I follow this comment and rewrite my code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-received-response