# Make Soap Client To The WSDL Web Service

Tags: c#, xml, soap, wsdl, xmlhttprequest

I want to make soap client to the WSDL web service. I will give it soap xml request and then it return soap response xml. And i searched tutorial to make request. I find this stackoverflow question.It is:

[Client to send SOAP request and received response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-received-response)

With this question i can get response xml from wsdl web service. But I don't want to use soap request xml as string like as:

```
soapEnvelop.LoadXml(@"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema""><SOAP-ENV:Body><HelloWorld xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/""><int1 xsi:type=""xsd:integer"">12</int1><int2 xsi:type=""xsd:integer"">32</int2></HelloWorld></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>");
```

I want to create this request xml with c# code. So that i searched tutorial again. And i find this tutorial:

[How to construct a soap service request using C# for HTTPWebRequest?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ed36e83f-9b0a-4a73-8ca3-1b9ecb524f06/how-to-construct-a-soap-service-request-using-c-for-httpwebrequest?forum=wcf)

But i can't merge this two tutorial. I am new this subject. How can i create soap request without using string soap xml to get soap xml response. The response can be xml as string. Because i can parse it in web page with javascript.

**Thanks for your suggestions.**

Comment: The example uses wr.GetRequestStream().Write(string).  So all you have to do is to take the xml you create and make it a string.  With XmlDocument use OuterText.  With XDocument use ToString().

Comment: I want to ask question to you. For example i have one wsdl web service which return soap response xml. To get this soap xml response, how many ways can I follow ?

Comment: Add [Service Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) to WSDL to your project. It will generate service client code. Then use it!