# Can't get response from SOAP 1.2 Web Request in C# Console app

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I am unable to hit a SOAP 1.2 web service with C# code. I followed the code in this example, [Web Service SOAP Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-received-response)

It does not work for me. My web service URL works in SOAPUI but I can't get a response in my C# code. I get a "500 Internal error." The status reads "ProtocolError." [image: ProtocolError]

I am running this from my Visual Studio 2017 editor.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace testBillMatrixConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                string _url = @"https://service1.com/MSAPaymentService/MSAPaymentService.asmx";
                var _action = @"http://schemas.service1.com/v20060103/msapaymentservice/AuthorizePayment";
            try
            {
                XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
                InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

                // begin async call to web request.
                IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

                // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
                // do something usefull here like update your UI.
                asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

                // get the response from the completed web request.
                string soapResult;
                using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
                {
                    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    Console.Write(soapResult);
                }



            }
            catch (WebException ex)
                {

                throw;//ex.Message.ToString();

            }

        }

        private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope()
        {
            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeDocument = new XmlDocument();
            soapEnvelopeDocument.LoadXml(@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:msap=""http://schemas.service1.com/v20060103/msapaymentservice""><soap:Body><msap:AuthorizePayment><!--Optional:--><msap:clientPaymentId>?</msap:clientPaymentId><msap:amount>?</msap:amount><msap:method>?</msap:method><!--Optional:--><msap:parameters><!--Zero or more repetitions:--><msap:PaymentParameter><!--Optional:--><msap:Name>?</msap:Name><!--Optional:--><msap:Value>?</msap:Value></msap:PaymentParameter></msap:parameters></msap:AuthorizePayment></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");
            return soapEnvelopeDocument;
        }

        private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }

        private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In SoapUI you are supplying question marks (`?`) as values for all the elements in the xml?

Comment: yes. The service will handle them and I am still just trying to get connectivity working.