# How to extract data from WSDL in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract the data from the Web Service WSDL Url. When I am trying to hit that URL I am getting an XML page. After doing some research, I have managed to add Service References in Visual Studio 2015. For checking the data  I have created the web Form and wrote the following lines of codes.

On `btn_click` function, I have added:

```
FM2CRM.RequestInfo connect = new FM2CRM.RequestInfo();
FM2CRM.FMInteractWebServiceClient getdata= new FM2CRM.FMInteractWebServiceClient();
```

> URL: https://dovevivo.fmshosted.com/TST_FMIWebservices/FMInteractWebService.svc?wsdl

But how I have to call the function? I am not getting it.

I am very new to C#.

Comment: Use svc util to generate C# client code from wsdl https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe

Comment: Have a look at this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-received-response

Comment: See the following article how to use generated by Add service reference code https://philmunro.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/generating-wcf-service-proxy-classes-using-svcutil/

Comment: What is the problem to call getdata.YourMethodName(); Your service url cannot be reached.

Comment: Just open FM2CRM.FMInteractWebServiceClient (press F12 on this class) and see which methods are available.