# C# Calling web service without references like the class "SoapClient" in php

Tags: c#, php

This is a php code I was testing

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient('URL?WSDL');

$parametros = array(
'VALUE1' => '123456',
'VALUE2' => ''  
);       

$result = $soapClient->__soapCall("METHOD_NAME", array($parametros));
```

I know in C# I can add a reference to my project and then I'll be able to consume the web service, but I'd like to know if it's possible to consume it as I did in PHP, where I don't need to add any references to my project. I'm having a hard time when running the application on the server, so I wanted to test something out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-received-response

Comment: I've already tried that and didn't work

Answer (score -1):

To create wcf services without using references, you must create an interface and create signatures for the services in the service. It's a very long time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/calling-a-rest-style-service-from-a-wcf-servi by

If you have web api in the client who gives you the service, you can do it in php.