# Client to send file attachment with a SOAP request

Tags: c#, .net, soap, multipart

I just need an extension to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791932/880875
to allow sending me a file with this SOAP request. In my case the service is soap based java web service.

Comment: Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms996944(v=msdn.10)

Comment: Sorry, but I went through it already, I just want to attach the file through the endpoint exposed by wcf. And I am not getting that from the link.

Comment: @DeepakMishra the article tells you how to do that, with sample code. What else do you need to know?

Comment: @TomW Which article?

Comment: @DeepakMishra the one that you responded to on the comment immediately prior to mine.

Comment: @TomW Actually that tells me how to create a webservice which has the response with attachment. My requirement is send a file as an attachment to a web service request. I have searched the whole internet but did not get any example of it. Please help.