# ASP.NET Web Service Root Element is Missing (Console Application) C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, service

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I'm trying to connect to my webservice that's hosted on IIS on a vm. I am able to connect to my web service through Microsoft Edge on my computer and via localhost on the vm.

I'm trying to connect to it through a console application on my computer through Visual Studio that uses the POST method. I've tried the GET method which works fine, but I want to be able to use the POST method.

Here is my console application...

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("WebServiceUrl");
        request.Method = "POST";
        WebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            response = request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch(WebException exception)
        {
            using (response = exception.Response)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(response);
        string res = response.ToString();
        Stream ReceiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

        // Pipe the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);
        Console.WriteLine("\nResponse stream received");
        Char[] read = new Char[256];

        // Read 256 charcters at a time.    
        int count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256);
        Console.WriteLine("HTML...\r\n");

        while (count > 0)
        {
            // Dump the 256 characters on a string and display the string onto the console.
            String str = new String(read, 0, count);
            Console.Write(str);
            count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");
        // Release the resources of stream object.
        readStream.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is the exception I am getting...

Error code: InternalServerError
soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> Root element is missing.

Some help would be great, as I'm a bit lost on what's causing the error in the console application. Thank you.

Comment: Can you mention the full exception ?

Comment: This is a SOAP error. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-receive-response