# In soap, I want to pass a namespace to the header tag in C#

Tags: c#, soap, header, namespaces

I am trying to implement web service in a web application. the web service requires credentials to be sent in the header. Also in the header tag, there is a namespace. I used a class inherited from AddressHeader to add the credentials but now I need to add a namespace to that header.
Here is the result XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <wes:auth xmlns:wes="http://asdf.org">
            <u>tester</u>
            <p>tester</p>
        </wes>
    </soap:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <get:GetCustomer xmlns:get="http://werty.org">
            ...
        </get:GetCustomer>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like doing this with xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication151
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string user = "jsmith";
            string password = "abcdefg";
            string inputs =
                "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                    "<soap:Header xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                        "<wes:auth xmlns:wes=\"http://asdf.org\">" +
                        "</wes:auth>" +
                    "</soap:Header>" +
                    "<soapenv:Body>" +
                        "<get:GetCustomer xmlns:get=\"http://werty.org\">" +
                        "</get:GetCustomer>" +
                    "</soapenv:Body>" +
                "</soapenv:Envelope>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(inputs);
            XElement wes = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "auth").FirstOrDefault();
            List<XElement> authorization = new List<XElement>() {
                new XElement("u", user),
                new XElement("p", password)
            };
            wes.Add(authorization);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but this way I cannot call the web service as Soap call.

Comment: Why not?  You can get a string using doc.ToString();

Comment: How will you pass the XML string to the soap call?

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-receive-response

Comment: Unfortunately, on the server-side, it is not allowed to send a request as REST, it should be SOAP

Comment: Most of the references in the link are SOAP, not REST.

Comment: Even though, I am getting the following:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope>
    <Header/>
    <Body>
        <Fault>
            <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring/>
            <detail type="faultDetails"/>
        </Fault>
    </Body>
</Envelope>

Comment: SOAP is xml which is what you are returning.  I think you have REST and SOAP backwards.  See : https://www.guru99.com/comparison-between-web-services.html