# SOAP Request action

Tags: c#, php, web, soap

Hello everyone,

I'm doing a request in SoapUI like in the photo below and I'm trying to make the same request in a SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio...
I kind of copied the functions needed for creating the webRequest from here [Client to send SOAP request and receive response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-receive-response) but I'm kind of stuck now because of the action.
What do I need to write for the action? In my case there is a php, I'm a bit confused.
I've tried couple of things but the response remains the same.. ( -1 )

[image]

The SoapUI request

[image]

There is this WS-A panel with some info as well about the request

[image]

Also, here is my envolope for the request... just in case

[image]

I've tried adding the web reference in **another project** and this is what I got ( I'm not allowed to use a web reference to this unfortunately.. )

[image]

I appreciate your time spent, thank you!

Comment: Your third image shows a screen for WS-Addressing, but none of your other screens show any SOAP headers for WS-Addressing. That action you are referring to seems to be useless. Have you tried ignoring it and just making the call to the `https://stg-ccon.cnh.com/ccon/cconWsConnect.php` endpoint? Make the call with SoapUI and, if successful, try to build a similar request in your code.

Comment: The SoapUI call works fine, it returns me what I want. :) I'm just trying to replicate this in C# ( without using a web reference ).

Comment: So you are asking how to make a http call with an xml body? Or something else?

Comment: I eventually did it, only needed to set the action to "" and my response was all good :D