# Getting SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I'm trying to request SOAP web service in my .NET project. I was able to connect and get the response using the SoapUI. But when I try to request using this as a reference [Client to send SOAP request and receive response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-receive-response)

I'm getting the `The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.`

[image]

The url and action I'm using:

`var _url = "https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/payment/services/SYNCAPIRequestMgrService";`

`var _action = "SYNCAPIRequestMgrService";`

Comment: see: https://www.google.com/search?q=The+SSL+connection+could+not+be+established%2C+see+inner+exception.&oq=The+SSL+connection+could+not+be+established%2C+see+inner+exception.&aqs=chrome..69i57.275123j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the response after putting this line of code before making the actual request.

`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };`

But this will always trust the SSL certificates and seems insecure.