# How to create a client web service that send data with secure token to another soap web service in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, client, webapi

I should send data from each client to a soap web service with secure token. what type of project I can use to create a local web api in client send data to web service with secure token in C# and VisualStadio ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have some clients that post and get data to and from an external soap API we want implement an API to manage that locally and run on server but clients cant access the soap server API because secure tokens connected to clients and API cant access that tokens I want implement some local APIs that run on clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot to unpack here.

- Firstly you want to create an API in your client. An API is an endpoint, meaning it is on the server not your client. A client consumes an API. PLus you are using SOAP so API isn't applicable at all.
- There is a good post about how to make a SOAP request: [Client to send SOAP request and receive response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-receive-response)

Comment: My main question was how to create a Windows service that allows communication with the desired server through a security token, is it necessary to run a service point on the client side, or is it possible to create an endpoint in the server that is responsible for sending information. to the desired service with a security token installed on the client

Comment: Both are possible. If the server already exists and you can't modify it then you can implement code in your client to retrieve the data.